# Convergence on $L_p$ spaces

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to justify a simple result on convergence over $L_p$ spaces.

The lemma is the following: Let $1\leq p<\infty$ and $0\leq f_k\nearrow f$ be measurable functions. Then $f_k\rightarrow f$ in $L_p$ if and only if $\sup||f_k||_p<\infty.$

I already have the $\Longleftarrow$ direction and I think the other should be the immediate one, but I do not seem to be able to justify it. Any hint would be useful! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is true in all normed spaces and convergent sequences.
By definition of convergence
$$\exists N, \forall n \geq N: ||f_n - f||_p \leq 1 $$
Consequence of the triangly-inequality:
$$||f_n||_p \leq ||f_n-f||_p+||f||_p $$
Combine the previous two:
$$||f_n||_p \leq 1 + ||f||_p $$
Take $\sup$
$$\sup_{n \geq N} ||f_n||_p \leq 1 + ||f||_p \leq \infty $$

EDIT: If $f_k \rightarrow f$ in $L_p$ then $f \in L_p$. To see this:
$f_k \rightarrow f$ so $f_k$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L_p$. By the completeness of $L_p$ there exists one and only one $g \in L_p$ such that $f_k \rightarrow g$. Now $||g-f||_p \leq ||g-f_k||_p+||f_k-f||_p$ wich goes to zero for $k \rightarrow \infty$. So $f = g \in L_p$

Comment: don't we need to assume then that $f\in L_p$? or is that a consequence of the fact that all $f_k$ are in $L_p$?

Comment: thank you! that was clear!

Comment: knowing that $f\in L_p$ isn't the result even more immediate? is it incorrect to say $\sup||f_k||_p\leq ||f||_p$ and hence the result?

Comment: The statement isn't correct. Counterexample: 
Let $f_k$ be such a sequence. Construct the new sequence:
$(g_k) = (2f, f_0,f_1,f_2, \ldots )$. So $g_0 = 2f$ and $g_{k+1}=f_k$.
Then $\sup ||g_k||_p \geq ||g_0||_p = 2 ||f||_p$ wich is bigger than $||f||_p$ if $f \neq 0$. Furthermore we have $g_k \rightarrow f$.

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but the $f_k$ are increasing, I mean $f_1\leq f_2\leq f_3\leq ...$

Comment: I'm gonna edit the question. Sorry about that

Comment: Oh then it is correct. We have $f_k \leq f \Rightarrow ||f_k||_p \leq ||f||_p$
Because $f_k^p \leq f^p$. 
No problem.